# How to optimize pySFeel import time - a Python module with complex decorators?

Tags: python, optimization, import, module

I write and maintain a Python module (pyDMNrules) and it takes 15s to load.

```
$ time python3 -c "import pyDMNrules"

real    0m14.625s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Now it imports another module that I write and maintain (`pySFeel`) which takes 14s to load.

```
$ time python3 -c "import pySFeel"

real    0m13.555s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

And pySFeel imports sly, which is fast to load.

```
$ time python3 -c "import sly"

real    0m0.218s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So I know where the problem lies - in pySFeel, which is basically a compiler/interpreter/executor of a completely different programming language (FEEL). pySFeel is a lot of tiny functions (6.2k lines of code). Admittedly with complex decorators. It builds a lexer and a parser at load time, which means a lot of compiling of regular expressions. I'm not familiar with the internals of sly, which it uses for its YACC like parsing. And I have no idea of where to go for information on optimising a Python module at load time. But 15s does seem a tad slow on a 2-year old i7 with 32gig RAM.

Load time was not a consideration in the design; pyDMNrules builds a rules engine that should be built once and called many times. But I was expecting users to be able to use it in testing/debugging/connectathon/hacking situations

Comment: Parsing is an expensive task but the time is indeed pretty huge. IDK the size of the input file but this operation can be cached if the input are the same (checks are possible with a hash). Besides the module uses yacc.py which appear to call Python functions that can be slow compared to the native implementation (it might be the price to pay for using pure python code).